# read csv file as a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I accidentally corrupted a csv file (delimiters no longer working - thanks Microsoft Excel!). I want to salvage some data by reading it as a string and searching for things - I can see the text by opening the file on notepad, but I can't figure out how to load that string from the filepath in python.

I imagine it would be a variation of

```
csv_string = open(filepath, 'something').read()
```

but I can't get it to work, or find a solution on SO / google.

Comment: A sample of your corrupted file, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, the file is huge with very little relevant information - it's just a csv file with delimiters removed. I'm still not sure how I would make a useful sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with the following code, but it is not the best way to deal with csv.

```
csv_string = ''.join(open(filepath, 'r').readlines())
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I know it's not the best, this is just to recover a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```py
with open(filepath, 'r') as corrupted_file:
    for line in corrupted_file:
        print(line) # Or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read csv from this .

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("samples/sample.csv"))    
for title, year, director in reader:
   print year, title
```

Comment: OP did not mention anything about `title, year, director`